# sorting tuple based on int column in python

Tags: python, sorting, int, tuples

I have the following tuple:

```
['Southampton', '9', '14', '13']
['Nottingham Forest', '8', '10', '17']
['Coventry City', '7', '4', '14']
['Blackburn Rovers', '4', '6', '14']
['Newcastle United', '24', '20', '10']
['FC Wimbledon', '21', '20', '11']
['Arsenal', '21', '19', '8']
```

And i want to sort it by the 2nd and 3rd column. So i use the following code:

```
sorted_rank = sorted(temp_rank, key=itemgetter(1,2), reverse=True)
```

But as you can see the 2nd and 3rd column is not int, so the sorting process finished wrong. How can i "tell" to python that these columns are int and not string?

I tried this but nothing:

```
sorted_rank = sorted(temp_rank, key=itemgetter(1,int(2)), reverse=True)
```

Comment: You might want to consider converting all the strings to integers first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify a custom function or lambda instead.

The following works:

```
sorted_rank = sorted(temp_rank, key=lambda i: (int(i[1]), int(i[2])), reverse=True)
```

where `sorted_rank` becomes:

```
[['Newcastle United', '24', '20', '10'],
 ['FC Wimbledon', '21', '20', '11'],
 ['Arsenal', '21', '19', '8'],
 ['Southampton', '9', '14', '13'],
 ['Nottingham Forest', '8', '10', '17'],
 ['Coventry City', '7', '4', '14'],
 ['Blackburn Rovers', '4', '6', '14']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def key_fct(tup):
    return (int(tup[1]), int(tup[2]))

sorted_rank = sorted(temp_rank, key=key_fct, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand why what you tried doesn't work, let's make sure you understand what `itemgetter(1, 2)` is. First off, `itemgetter` is a function. But more importantly, it's a function that returns a function, and that returned function is what you're using as the key function for your sort. To see why your attempt at casting your strings to ints didn't work, let's implement a version of `itemgetter` that always takes two arguments:

```py
def itemgetter(i, j):
    def fn(e):
        return (e[i], e[j])
    return fn
```

What's used as a key is the return value of the inner function, `fn`. What you did was cast `j` to an int, not `e[j]`. In order to do that, you have to capture the result of `fn`, perform the cast, and then return the results:

```py
def keyfunc(e):
    return tuple(int(x) for x in itemgetter(1, 2)(e))
```

And then you can perform your sort correctly using that:

```py
sorted_rank = sorted(temp_rank, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)
```